# Custom Post save causes 500 error

Tags: custom-post-types, wpdb, php, wp-update-post

Been having issues with getting a 500 error.  Sometimes a change is saved, usually not.  I've output the $key/$values to verify it's reaching the function and foreach.  The output is the first key/value pair over and over...

I'm approaching this this way because I will have an unknown number of "officers" that will be output as a custom post type.

```
$name = 'officer' . '-' . $officer_id . '-' . $count;
    ?>
        <label for="<?php echo $name; ?>">Officer #<?php echo $count; ?></label>    
        <input type="text" name="<?php echo $name; ?>" value="<?php echo $officer_info[0]->post_title; ?>">
        <br />
    <?php
    $count++;
```

I tried entering officers as an array:

```
$name = 'officer' . '-' . $officer_id . '-' . $count;
    ?>
        <label for="['<?php echo $name; ?>']">Officer #<?php echo $count; ?></label>    
        <input type="text" name="<?php echo $name; ?>" value="<?php echo $officer_info[0]->post_title; ?>">
```

With the id as the key, no change.

I've tried continue if 'officer' isn't in the $key with no change.  I tried 'pre_post_update' instead of 'save_post' with no change.  I've added priority and number (10, 2) of variables with no change.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'officers_onto_board_page_save', 10, 2 );
function officers_onto_board_page_save( $post_id ) {
    global $wpdb;

    // if our current user can't edit this post, bail
    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) {
        return;
    } 

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $item) {
        echo $key . ' , ' . $item;

        if (strpos($key, 'officer') == 0) {
            $parts = explode('-', $key);

            $my_post = array(
                  'ID'           => $parts[1],
                  'post_title'   => $item
              );
            wp_update_post( $my_post );
        }
    } 
}
```

Any suggestions/recommendations would be appreciated.

example response: _wpnonce , dc7a6eaea0_wpnonce , dc7a6eaea0_wpnonce , dc7a6eaea0_wpnonce , dc7a6eaea0_wpnonce , dc7a6eaea0_wpnonce , dc7a6eaea0_wpnonce , dc7a6eaea0_wpnonce , dc7a6eaea0 (over and over)

Comment: Is there anything useful in the server logs when the 500 error occurs?

Comment: Aric, found an answer before checking the logs.  Great suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer.

Essentially I had an infinite loop that was quite puzzling at first.  It made more sense as I saw that it never iterated beyond the first item in the post array.

I found the answer here:
https://tommcfarlin.com/update-post-in-save-post-action/

The issue is that wp_update_post hooks into save_post...  so every time I would reach that, it would restart again.  To fix this, I changed my code to read:

```
function officers_onto_board_page_save( $post_id ) {
    remove_action( 'save_post', 'officers_onto_board_page_save' );


    //DO STUFF


   add_action( 'save_post', 'officers_onto_board_page_save');
}
```

By removing the function and then re-adding it to `save_post`, it operates as expected.